# How to customize TaxReport_IT - report SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I would like to custom the Report SSRS **TaxReport_IT**, I need to add a new field in order to use in to *SyntethicReport* Design.

*(for example)*

[image]

The classes involved seems these:
TaxReport_IT
TaxReportDP_IT
TaxReportController_IT
TaxReportContract_IT

Tables involved:
TmpTaxReport_ITSummary
TmpTaxReport_IT
TaxReportTmp_IT

*Are there others?* *Are there some Queries involved?'*

I added the new fields in to table _TmpTaxReport_IT_, and I pupulated the related tables
[image]
[image]

I'm sure, in to the method I pupulated correctly the new Field (I have the values ​​that I expect), but when I print the Report I get a lower value. Seems like I don't take the total data set.

How can I add the new field and take the correctly total value?
I saved the data (about my custom field in a RegularTable) and the sum is correct, but I have mismatch when I print the report.
I think I skip some step to Report DataSet.

I use Dynamics AX 2012.

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an idea what could be wrong, but I'm making some assumptions. If they are not correct, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59712057/edit) your question to clarify.

From your screenshot, it looks like you want to add your new custom field in the header section of the report design. I'm assuming the expression of that field looks similar to

`=First(Fields!MyCustomFIELD.Value, "TaxReportDS_IT")`

Note the `First` key word in that expression. This indicates that the value for that field should be taken from the first of the records of the report's dataset.

I'm assuming that you calculate the value of the field while the records in table `TaxReportTmp_IT` are being created so that each record has a different value. Maybe it is a sum of some other field, so the first record would have the smallest value and the last record the highest.

If all those assumptions are correct, you can fix this by changing the `First` keyword to `Last`. This indicates that you want to take the value of the last record of the report data set.

See also the documentation of the [Last Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-last-function?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @FH-Inway.
I checked through debug, and the classes and tables behind process are below.
Classes:

TaxReportController_IT

TaxReport_IT

Tables:

TaxReportPayment_IT

TaxBookSection

TmpTaxReport_ITSummary

TaxReportTmp_IT

TmpTaxReport_IT